# long ajax calls - how to avoid network timeout

Tags: php, ajax, asynchronous, promise

In a web app I have some ajax calls to multiple long running php scripts (its OK that the user will wait). However I'm about to add AWS cloudfront in front of the server for security which will cause timeout after 180sec (its the maximum allowed).

I need to implement a mechanism to run the long scripts on the server side and poll the results from the browser.
One option is :

```
On the server side:
We create a script 'async_call' which receives the file to call in addition to the url params and does the following:

1 - calc hash for the the call (used for storing/getting apc info for this call)

2 - if status in apc value indicates not running
2.1 - Store in call-status-APC-<hash> the call status as running 
2.2 - Call the script file using curl with params and cookies without timeout
2.3 - when the data returns store it in return-value-APC-<hash> and return it.

3 - If the apc status indicates running
3.1 Poll for results in the return-value-APC-<hash> every few seconds and if exist delete and return it.

On the client side:
Ajax has retry functionality so if it times out it will call again. so:
1 - change from calling ajax_file.php -> async_call?file=ajax_file.php&all-other-params
2- set ajax retry (e.g. 10)
```

Is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: I think you need some kind of queuing system if you don't want to set the server timout time to infinity. I recommend using something like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-php.html) if you don't want to write it yourself.

Comment: Maybe run the long-running task in a cron job, or a queue server as mentioned above, which reports its progress to a log (e.g. in a file or DB) frequently. And then have the AJAX just poll a status page which reports from the log. And/or use SSE or websockets to reduce the amount of calls flying back and forth to the webserver.

Comment: @toffler the server timeout is controllable and sufficient. its something that is running and I'm adding cloudfront in front of it thus the 180 sec timeout

Comment: @ADyson these tasks outputs a response to users... its not suitable for a cron job.

Comment: @Nir did you not read what I said about logging the status? That way you can indirectly output the values to users - the cron job outputs its progress into the log, and the status page reads from the log at frequent intervals, or even in real-time. That way you have a disconnected architecture which doesn't rely on long-running HTTP requests, but you can still see output quite easily.

Comment: @ADyson the call is initiated by a user its not something global so cron is less suitable since it requires a scheduler overhead and does not run on demand.

Comment: The user would still initiate the task, but their request would be logged in a task queue of some sort (can just be a DB table, in the simplest case). Then the job scheduler / queue manager, when it runs, picks up the next unstarted / uncompleted task from the queue and processes it. It then proceeds as I described above. This will scale well too - if you need to you can have multiple background processes all taking jobs off the queue and executing them in parallel.